# Failed to get adb version; error = 13 in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I added 32-bit android adk to eclipse(Classic, Indigo, Version: 3.7.0
Build id: I20110613-1736) in Ubuntu 11.10. I use 32-bit Ubuntu. When I start Eclipse the following error occurs.

Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/adb":java.io.IOException:error=13, Permission denied

I had already tried

```
1)set chmod -R 777 for android-sdk-linux_x86, platform-tools and adb. 

2)added jdk 6 as follows
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-bin 
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

But these two fixes doesn't work.
What will be the issue? and can  anyone guide me, to fix this issue?

Comment: have a look at this: http://android-eclipse.blogspot.com/2011/05/failed-to-get-adb-version-cannot-run.html

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS already tried that

Comment: this got resolved by just installing java to system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally the issue is fixed. The solution I tried is much similar to @cataxo's answer. In addition to adding the platform-tools I had to add the tools folder in the bashrc.

This is how I added the android paths in the bashrc file.

```
# Android tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools

export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME
```

For those who have this problem after adding this, if you still have this issue then please make sure that the java path is added. It may be like

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

The java version name may varry depending on the version installed on your machine. To find the version name type  java -version from terminal.

If still the issue exists then please check the permissions of avd folder, its contents and .android folder.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem. But my jdk version is 7 .
I solved it by doing the following steps:

1. ctrl+alt+t>>vi ~/.bashrc>>Add the path "android-sdk/platform-tools" to export Path= ....:Path
2. set chmod -R 777 android-sdk`

Comment: My path is ‘/user/local/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools’.  Do you add the correct path to ‘bashrc’? I mean your path may be different from mine .