# Error:java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Whenever i am creating the new project in the **Android Studio** , it gives me the same problem.

```
 Error:java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission
```

I have searched a lot about it but did not get the proper solution, following are the links which i have visited, please help me to short out these problem..Thanks

[1st Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343729/failed-to-get-adb-version-error-13-in-ubuntu-11-10) ,
[2nd Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118709/why-cant-i-run-the-android-emulator-java-io-ioexception-error-13-permission) ,
[3rd Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082857/errorandroid-apt-compiler-cannot-run-program-sdk-path-build-tools-21-1-2-aapt)

And below is the screen shot of my Android Studio, please look at it:-

[image]

Comment: What OS do you have ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna , its a Unix OS

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with Unix OS but as [discussed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180292), **If your system is a `64bit`, then you have to install the 32bit runtime libraries.**

And you can install that using this command line in the `Terminal`

```
yum install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. i will check it, and soon will inform you.. :)

Comment: And didn't you install yum using `sudo apt-get install yum` ?

Comment: I have deleted the comment, because i came to that it can be install by the sudo apt-get install yum ...anyways thanks a lot...i m checking it..give u soon reply

Comment: So sad, are those package installed ?

Comment: Yes bro..I have installed first yump and than after yum ***"install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686"**** ......... And it installed successfully ..But did not work bro..Any thanks, If u get the another better solution than plz let me know..For yours effort i marking +1 bro.... :)                       Plz let me know if you get the proper solution