# IOException: error=13, permission denied

Tags: java, android, busybox, toybox

I am trying to run some LINUX like commands from an android application, I want my application to run some custom commands like `pkg`, `dpkg` etc. basically I need my application to act as a terminal app, for this, I created a Linux file structure with necessary libraries and binaries inside the application package, i.e. I placed my files under the `/data/data/com.example.root.app/files/usr/bin` directory structure. Then I am executing them from my code:

```
Process process; 
try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"pkg","search","apache2"}, env, new File(cwd));
    } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO: Visible error message?
    }
```

I am using variable *env* to set the environment variables *PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, HOME* etc.. which I am passing to the process above. also, i start the process from the directory which contains the commands i.e

```
String cwd = "/data/data/com.example.root.app/files/usr/bin"
```

I am able to run rudimentary commands like `env`, `ls -l`, `pwd` but I am not able to run the custom-built commands like `pkg`.

when I try to execute the command `pkg` it throws *IOException error =13 permission denied*

please be informed that I have set the executable permissions to 777 recursively to the whole directory, just to find whether it runs, but it doesn't.

Also when I use already existing terminal application there I am able to run the `pkg` command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35933203/6113352 this might help

Comment: I think that your user has no permissions to run `pkg` commands, and that is the cause of error.

Comment: @Kurusu thanks for the link but its not related to my problem

Comment: but i have set executable permission to all, i have used chmod 777, so how is it permission problem?